# Замена вхождений букв в строке

Tags: visual-basic

Написать программу, в которой вначале по запросу вводится текстовая строка из латинских букв и вспомогательных символов. Требуется заменить в ней все вхождения малой буквы “а” на 1, малой буквы “b” на 22, “c” – на 333. Подсчитать в новой строке число цифр. Итоговую строку и число цифр выдать на экран. Получилось лишь вот что... но ничего не идет

```
Dim Len, k,m,n, i As Integer
Dim Str, StrNew As String
Dim Ch As Char
Str = InputBox("Введите строку из латинских букв и вспомогательных символов")
For i = 1 To Len 'Проход по строке Str
    Ch = Mid(Str, i, 1) 'Выделение очередного символа
    If Ch = "a" Then k = k + 1 ' Сравнение символа с буквой а и подсчет вхождений
    If Ch = "b" Then n = m + 22 ' Сравнение символа с буквой b и подсчет вхождений
    If Ch = "c" Then n = n + 333 ' Сравнение символа с буквой c и подсчет вхождений
Next i
MsgBox(" Число вхождений малой латинской буквы а равно ")
MsgBox(" Число вхождений малой латинской буквы b равно ")
MsgBox(" Число вхождений малой латинской буквы c равно ")
End
```

Comment: Хм. А где в вашем коде замена? Смотрите: `Ch = Mid(Str, i, 1)` получило очередной символ, `If Ch = "a"` проверило, не `"a"` ли это, а что делает дальше `k = k + 1` и что вам на самом деле надо? А ещё значение `Len` у вас нигде не вычисляется, откуда ж ему быть правильным?

Comment: что-то мне плохо от такого решения
может быть решить сначала задачу попроще, подсчёт только букв "a" например

Answer (score 1):

Len - слово зарезервировано, не стоит его объявлять, будут неопределённости.

```
Dim S as String, S_new as String, S_clear as String
Dim counterA as Integer
S = InputBox("Введите строку из латинских букв и вспомогательных символов")
' Заменяем
S_new = Replace(S, "a", "1")
S_new = Replace(S_new, "b", "22")
S_new = Replace(S_new, "c", "333")

' Убираем цифры из строки
S_clear = Replace(S_new, "1", "")
S_clear = Replace(S_clear, "2", "")
S_clear = Replace(S_clear, "3", "")
S_clear = Replace(S_clear, "4", "")
S_clear = Replace(S_clear, "5", "")
S_clear = Replace(S_clear, "6", "")
S_clear = Replace(S_clear, "7", "")
S_clear = Replace(S_clear, "8", "")
S_clear = Replace(S_clear, "9", "")
S_clear = Replace(S_clear, "0", "")

' Считаем, на сколько уменьшилась длина строки при удалении цифр
counterA = Len(S_new) - Len(S_clear)

MsgBox("Итоговая строка: " & S_new & "," & vbCrLf & "Число цифр: " & CStr(counterA))
```

Поясню: vbCrLf - это перевод строки. Соединяем разные строки при помощи амперсанда (**&**)